# Matching a hash character (#) with a regex

Tags: regex, xml

I have an XML document that contains a regular expression (so you don't need to escape with \). Basically I'm trying to match musical chord symbols, and this regex works fine, but refuses to match a hash:

```
\b[A-G](m|b|\#|sus|\d)*?\b
```

Comment: What regex engine are you using? You probably shouldn't be escaping the hash.

Comment: I believe its the .net regex engine, but in an XML file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `\b`, the word boundary anchor, only matches between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters, so it won't match after a `#` (unless that is itself followed by an alphanumeric).

Use

```
\b[A-G](?:m|b|#|sus|\d)*(?:\b|(?<=#))
```

No need to escape the `#`, either.

EDIT: Changed the regex to better reproduce the intended functionality (as I think it should be)

Currently, you're not matching some chords, though; how about

```
\b[A-G](?:add|maj|j|m|-|b|#|sus|\d|°)*(?:\b|(?<=[#°-]))
```

That way, you can match all of these:

```
A7
Abm7 
A#m7sus4
A7b9#13
Amaj7#11
A#°
Abj7add13
```

I guess there is still room for improvement, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer completely forgot that about the \b

Comment: Your longer example doesn't seem to work. I did escape the < by using a CDATA section, but the regex doesn't compile

Comment: Oops, I made a blunder in the character class at the end. Please try it now.

Comment: I have the same question but with a different regex in a different context. I can't get it to match a hash symbol. This answer doesn't help me. Not sure if I should ask a different question.. with a very slightly different title..

Comment: @Shavais: I guess a new question makes sense here. Maybe the difference in context could make it into the title?