# Regular expression with C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm attempting to find a regular expression that will match the following strings:

```
##Content##
##AnotherArea##
```

So far I've tried

```
@"\\#\\#(.*?)\\#\\#"
@"\\#\\#(*?)\\#\\#"
```

But neither seem to find anything when running:

```
foreach (var match in Regex.Matches(txtPageContent.Text, expressionMatch))
```

Where expression match is a string containing the expressions.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: There's no need to escape `#`

Comment: This SO Answer helps you to solve your issue. Please see to this.


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884915/matching-a-hash-character-with-a-regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no need to escape `#`.

```
##.*?##
```

simple explanation

```
Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match the characters “##” literally «##»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the characters “##” literally «##»
```

Comment: But I think he wants the sub-group match (or whatever that's called).

Comment: its still **OK** to escape it unless he uses verbatim string

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for the explanation as well. I know nothing about regex.